# Cleanup code to add div structure to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was cleaning up my code when I came across this situation :

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var count = 1;
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var rowStart = '<div class="row">';
    var cell = '<div class="c">';
    cell += '<div class="title">' + a[i] + '</div>';
    cell += '</div>';
    var rowEnd = '</div>';

    if (count == 1) {
        html += rowStart + cell;
        count++;
    } else if (count == 3) {
        html += cell + rowEnd;
        count = 1;
    } else {
        html += cell;
        count++
    }
}
$('#container').append(html);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/j4Bh9/2/)

I retrieve data from a database which I want to display in a `div` structure as shown above. This code however looks ugly and I think it can be way shorter, I just don't know how.

I was hoping someone could give me some advice/methods/anything on how to clean up this code.

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: I need support for all major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should let CSS handle most of the job for you. **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Bh9/10/)**

JS:

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var count = 1;
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var div = $("<div>" + a[i] + "</div>");
    $('#container').append(div);
}
```

CSS (where the magic is):

```css
#container div:nth-child(3n+1) { /* Every third! */
    clear: both;
}

#container div {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The general rule here is: What can reasonably be done with CSS over JavaScript, should be done with CSS over JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a [JavaScript Template Engine](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) to render raw data into HTML. JavaScript template engines also pair well with a view resolver like [Bloodhound](https://github.com/gburghardt/bloodhound) (which I wrote).

**Edit #1:** If you need something lighter weight this would suffice:

```
function render(template, data) {
    return template.replace(/#\{(\w+)}/g, function(tag, key) {
        return (key in data) ? data[key] : "";
    });
}
```

And to use:

```
var template = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML,
    html = render(template, {
        title: "Just a Render Test",
        price: 22.85
    });

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq8Jy/

Comment: Hmm never heard of template engines. I just looked into it but i think it's a bit too much for my goal isn't it?

Comment: It all depends on how many time you need to render a template. If this is the only place, then a template engine might be a bit much. Updating my answer with another idea.

Comment: To who ever down-voted my answer, I've updated it given @RobinvdA's comment.